# Error #2035 in some applications

Tags: 14.04

I am constantly getting a error#2035 when I want to see video clips.
Can someone help me.  I am totally not tech savvy.
I am an Ubuntu user

Terdon. We have a news24 website on which the videos do not work. I can watch Youtube and videos on saved files. I use 14.04. The notification on the screen of the embedded video player says error #2035 and then it does not play. What else do you need to know? Thanks for helping. – Henry Pratt

I use firefox
Here's link to one of the videos in News 24 that I am unable to watch on my PC
http://www.news24.com/Live/SouthAfrica/News/anc-chair-calls-zille-a-white-supremacist-20160223

I can watch this clip on my Smartphone.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more information. Where do you see this error message? In what application? What video clips? Any? Only some? Are these locally saved files or things like YouTube videos? What version of Ubuntu are you using? What other symptoms do you have? Can you still watch the video or does the error stop you? We can't help unless you give us something to go on.

Comment: Terdon.  We have a news24 website on which the videos do not work.  I can watch Youtube and videos on saved files.  I use 14.04.  The notification on the screen of the embedded video player says error #2035 and then it does not play.  What else do you need to know?  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Please [*edit*] your question and include the details you just gave (information is easy to miss in the comments and they can be deleted with no warning). Also tell us what browser you use and, if possible, provide a link to one of the problematic videos. Do they work for other people? Do they work from your phone or tablet if you have any?

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that first.  Why can I view them on my smartphone though?

Comment: That depends on all sorts of things. As I said, we can't help unless you *[edit]* your question and give us more information.

Answer (score 0):

This is a flash player error, a quick Google shows it is related to incompatible or outdated versions of flash.

Unfortunately adobe no longer releases flash updates for Linux, so it is likely unfixable in Firefox but you could try an alternative player like

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install freshplayerplugin
```

It is Google's `pepper flash` packaged for firefox but I have tried it and could not get it to work, though I did not try very hard.

Alternatively I can confirm the videos run in [Google Chrome](https://www.google.co.uk/chrome/browser/desktop/) (Pepper flash, like the repo above), so you could install chrome and use that.